# Azure Notification Hub unable to upload .p12 for APN

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub, apn

I am not able to upload a .p12 for APN. and this is the error message I received. Any idea what cause this error?

```
SubCode=40000. Failed to validate credentials with APNS. Error is The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized..TrackingId:b18f483e-6285-9d5b-895c-12e2fcc26dcf_M1_G12,TimeStamp:4/21/2014 3:16:19 AM
```

Answer (score 65):

I was having the same issue while uploading the certificate on the backend and finally found the solution after lot of struggling. Do the following:

1. Select keys from your keychain
2. Locate desired push private key
3. Click the small arrow to expand the key & profile
4. Now select the certificate only (this is a crucial step) no both the key & certificate ONLY SELECT CERTIFICATE and click for export
5. Set password for your exported certificate and upload

Have a look at this picture for reference:

[image]

Comment: You saved my day, with the crucial step (4), thanks a lot. Same for google play game services...

Comment: very good, i followed the steps but it still didn't upload. so i thought id try and upload from azure classic portal and it uploaded without a problem!!

Comment: Apple really need to make this process harder ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I thought I would post something that worked for me as well. Seeing as the .p12 file was created by another part of our company I was not able to get the .p12 file re-exported in the correct manner.

Instead I imported the .p12 to my local certificate store (windows) and then re-exported as a pfx.

[image: Import the p12 file, making sure to mark as exportable]

Take a note of where the certificate is stored
[image: Take a note of where the certificate is stored]

Then, [Use the MMC tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-view-certificates-with-the-mmc-snap-in) to view and export your certificate, making sure to export the private key as part of the pfx.

[image: export the private key as part of the pfx]

(You should probably delete the certificate from your local machine after the export is complete.)

After that you should be able to import your new pfx file into azure via the portal.