# Error uploading .p12 for Apple Push notifications to Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

Receiving this error when attempting to upload my .p12 certificate file in "Apple notification settings" within an Azure Notification Hub. This worked a few months ago when I tested it, but doesn't seem to be working now. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

```
SubCode=40000. Failed to validate credentials with APNS. Error is A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.. TrackingId:63386d51-c7c0-5778-b5e7-3d82512297e6_M2_G7,TimeStamp:12/23/2014 1:56:32 AM
```

I even tested creating a new notification hub, but still run into the same error.

My error is different to this, and his suggestion didn't work for me :( 
[Azure Notification Hub unable to upload .p12 for APN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23190517/41211)

Thanks guys

Comment: Have you checked if sandbox/prod APNS cert is uploaded for sandbox/prod NH mode?

Comment: Yes, well I ensured it was a prod cert and uploading as prod in NH.

Comment: I had the same issue, so i tried to re-upload and it worked.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm getting a different error but the same problem.

Comment: how did you solve this error ?