# I can't upload P12 certificate to Azure (iOS Push Notifications)

Tags: ios, azure, apple-push-notifications

I'm getting the following error when I try to upload a .p12 certificate to Azure:

```
{"error":{"message":"SubCode=40000. Only 3 properties ApnsCertificate, CertificateKey and Endpoint are required.
```

I followed the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26038331/4838107) post and they didn't work.
What is the problem?

Comment: You may try the old portal to upload the certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by using a password when I exported the .p12 file from Keychain access (before I was leaving the fields empty).  Might be a fluke but looks like a bug for now.  In fact, you don't even have to export it with a password.  In the Azure portal, when prompted for a password, put something in, delete it, and submit.  My co-worker tried this and Azure accepted the cert.

Answer (score 1):

I was previously able to upload .p12 certificate files to an Azure Notification Hub. 
Today I logged in to a dev hub that had previously accepted a certificate a few weeks ago and I deleted its certificate and then tried immediately to re-upload it [the same cert, the same file that previously worked] just to show a junior dev how the process worked and I got that same error.

I think Microsoft probably needs to push up a fix to this issue; the UI is always changing in Azure and this might just be a temporary regression in functionality.  Either that or something has changed about what they accept but I don't see anything to indicate that.

Comment: I still got the same error when I tried this morning.  I will try again tomorrow and see if anything has changed.

Comment: I tried it a couple of times today, it worked after a few tries, for what it's worth I tried to delete the (already-deleted?) certificate and even tried the putting a character in the password field and deleting it and then it worked, thus incorporating the other answers

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the exact same issue yesterday and just now but it's fixed now. This is what I have done.

1. Follow the same instruction exporting the certificate and setting the password.
2. Click "Delete Certificate" next to "Upload Certificate".  I think this is the step that somehow fixes the issue. (I know the error message isn't very helpful)
3. Upload the exported certificate.

Sorry, I can't really figure out a rational explanation.