# Why does my xamarin iOS app fail to register with Azure Notification Hub in release mode?

Tags: ios, xamarin, azure-notificationhub

I confirm that a device has registered by using the Azure Notification Hub explorer in VS and looking for the unique tag I set with the device. Only my development iphone and any android phones have successfully registered. Other iphones included in the beta app tester list through itunesconnect silently fail although the app does make it through each successful step in the code without any errors. These phones are also not included in the provisioning profile used for development but I don't think that matters since the app works entirely with just this issue as the only exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Azure deleted my Production certificate and didn't tell me.

They initially accept the cert but then find that it contains the key and remove it later without warning or notice.

This person already found the solution to creating an acceptable cert without key

[Azure Notification Hub unable to upload .p12 for APN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190517/azure-notification-hub-unable-to-upload-p12-for-apn/26038331#26038331)